# PowerShell List users in groups with managers but cannot format manager field

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've written this from scratch, so if there's a better approach, appreciate any suggestions.

I'm trying to list all users from multiple AD groups, by using a wildcard for the AD group names, and include info per user including their manager.
This works, but I can't figure out how to format the manager field better; it returns as the full DN.
I've tried:

- Formatting $mgr as a string (.length etc. but that doesn't work, can't seem to convert it into a string either)
- Format as an array (only has 1 value)
- I think it's an object but can't format it
- Format as an expression (my first go) - it sort of works, but displays the field name in each row

How can I format the manager field better, or return the managers name to begin?
The final data is actually being exported into a CSV, hence getting the formatting correct.

Thanks,
Piers

```
Clear-Host

$FilterToUse = "grp-Servers-Win-"

$FilterToUse2 = $FilterToUse + "*"
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like $FilterToUse2}
$headers = "GroupName,Network ID,Name,UserType,Check"
Write-Host $headers

ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember $group | ForEach-Object {
        $mgr = Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -Properties manager | Select -Property manager
        #$mgr = Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -Properties manager | Select @{label='ad-manager';expression={$_.manager -replace '^CN=|,.*$'}}

        if ($_.samaccountname -like "ZZZ*") {
            Write-host ($Group.Name + "," + $_.samaccountname + "," + $_.name + "," + $_.objectclass + ",CatA," + $mgr)
            }
        elseif ($_.samaccountname -like "YYY*") {
            Write-Host ($Group.Name + "," + $_.samaccountname + "," + $_.name + "," + $_.objectclass + ",CatB," + $mgr)
        }
        elseif ($_.samaccountname -like "XXX*") {
            Write-Host ($Group.Name + "," + $_.samaccountname + "," + $_.name + "," + $_.objectclass + ",CatC," + $mgr)
        }
        else {
            Write-Host ($Group.Name + "," + $_.samaccountname + "," + $_.name + "," + $_.objectclass + ",check," + $mgr)
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you want the manager as an ADUser object, you will need to do an additional query: `Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -Properties manager | Select -ExpandProperty manager | get-aduser`. If you want to manipulate the DN string, you need to return the property value rather than a custom object with the property: `Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -Properties manager | Select -ExpandProperty manager`. Notice `-ExpandProperty` being used.

Comment: @AdminOfThings is right, if you want to retrieve only the name of the manager, here the full line : `$mgr = Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -Properties manager | Select -ExpandProperty manager | Get-ADUser | Select -ExpandProperty Name`. And you should avoid curly brackets for filters so prefer this `$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter "name -like '$FilterToUse2'"`

Comment: That's fab, thanks all for explaining & v quick answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment above, but to explain what's going on more simply:

```
 $mgr = (Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -Properties Manager | Select-Object Manager).Manager -replace '^CN=|,.*$'
```

or

```
 $mgr = (Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -Properties Manager | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manager) -replace '^CN=|,.*$'
```

Comment: To cover the rare cases where a user's RDN contains commas (e.g. Smith, John), I would suggest using the regex of ^CN=|,(OU|CN)=.*$|\\,

Comment: Comment @AdminOfThings for the question is a better way to achieve the goal. Why ? Just because a regex will only extract something in the DN, while with the other way, you can easily get all information you want, far example : have surname only or emailAddress...

Comment: It is however extremely inefficient to process get-aduser twice if you don't need that info - especially in a For-Each loop. There are of course better ways to code what the OP is trying to do.